# upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination (503)

Tags: docker, ssl, webpack, google-cloud-platform, http2

I am trying to deploy a hellow-world node app to Cloud Run using `http2` with webpack (dockerized) and getting the above error. Locally it works fine (and also works fine with the docker run command). Here is my code:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14.15.3
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install -y
RUN npm i -g webpack webpack-dev-server -y
RUN npm install  webpack-cli -g
COPY . /app
CMD npm run dev -y
EXPOSE 8080
```

**webpack.config.js**

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
entry: './main.js',
mode: 'development',
devServer: {
    static: {
       directory: path.join(__dirname, "./")
    },
    historyApiFallback: true,
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 8080,
    http2: true,
    server: 'spdy',
    // sockPort and disableHostCheck fix viewing over ssh tunneled ports, e.g. with gitpod.io
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    },
output: {
   path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
   filename: 'bundle.js'
}   
};
```

Cloud run log

> 2022-06-20 23:56:29.624 IST
>
> GET
>
> 503
>
> 1.21 KiB
>
> 14 ms
>
> Chrome 81.0.4044.92 https://example.com/
>
> Curl result (on the cloud run url) vibhor@vibhor:~$ curl -i
> --http2-prior-knowledge https://example.com HTTP/2 503  content-length: 95 content-type: text/plain date: Mon, 20 Jun 2022
> 19:01:36 GMT server: Google Frontend x-cloud-trace-context:
> 35984e049ee66d2c95893802984bbed3/18320099253583711577;o=1 traceparent:
> 00-35984e049ee66d2c95893802984bbed3-fe3e113503c18d59-01 alt-svc:
> h3=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443";
> ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443";
> ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"
>
> upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset
> reason: connection termination

When I checked the cloud run documentation for http2 (https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/http2) it says

Your Cloud Run service must handle requests in HTTP/2 cleartext (h2c) format, because TLS is still terminated automatically by Cloud Run.

To confirm that your service supports h2c requests, test the service locally using this cURL command:

`curl -i --http2-prior-knowledge https://localhost:8080`

When I deployed locally and ran the command given above, it says:

> curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate
> More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.

Adding the `--insecure` option to above command works and gives

```
   HTTP/2 200
   x-powered-by: Express
   accept-ranges: bytes
   cache-control: public, max-age=0
   last-modified: Mon, 20 Jun 2022 03:56:22 GMT
   etag: W/"5f-1817f411ac4"
   content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
   content-length: 95
   vary: Accept-Encoding`enter code here`
```

Tried with port 443 as well and the behavior is the same. Also tried adding `http2: true` option to the webpack devserver but the result is the same

Could anyone suggest any changes I could do to make this work?

Comment: Q: What exactly are you trying to do?  Why are you trying to do it with webpack-dev-server???